# fillTriangle() in Blackberry JRE 5.0.0

Tags: blackberry, java

I'm seeing code and docs , but in my BB JRE doesn't appear this function in Graphics .

[Link of the docs](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/javax/microedition/lcdui/Graphics.html#fillTriangle%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `fillTriangle` is part of `javax.microedition.lcdui.Graphics` ,while you are using `net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics` which doesnt have that method.